# Kafka 2.0 - Multiple Kerberos Principals in KafkaConnect Connectors

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-dataflow

We are currently using HDF (Hortonworks Dataflow) 3.3.1 which bundles Kafka 2.0.0. Problem is with running multiple connectors with different configuration(Kerberos principals) on same KafkaConnect Cluster.

As part of this Kafka version, all connectors are supposed to use same consumer/producer properties which have been set in worker configuration with consumer.* or producer.* prefix. But as I stated, we have multiple users (apps) running their own connectors and we can't use a single Kerberos principal to allow read on all topics.

So just wanted to check with experts if there is any way this security limitation can be over come. The option I can think of is - run a different Kafka-Connect cluster for each Kafka User (different principals) but what implications it could have if we run many KafkaConnect Clusters on same nodes ? Will it cause any impacts in term of resources (Java heap etc.) or this is the only way (standard procedure) to handle  this.

PS: In later releases (2.3+) this problem is fixed via [KAFKA-8265](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8265) and these settings can be overwritten but even if we try upgrading to latest HDF we will only get Kafka 2.1 which will not solve this issue.

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: You can install Kafka Connect externally from HDF... And versions don't need to match

Comment: Thanks this helps. I will try that. Agree its not supported anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think upgrading is your best option to get the linked feature. As I commented, you can go get latest kafka versions on your own... Hortonworks/Cloudera doesn't offer support for Connect anyway. They'd rather you use Spark/Flink/NiFi (I think Storm is no longer around?)

> what implications it could have if we run many KafkaConnect Clusters on same nodes ? Will it cause any impacts in term of resources (Java heap etc.)

Heap is the main one (for batching, sink connectors). Network and CPU load could also come into account, depending on rate of messages.

As long as the advertised ports for each cluster process aren't colliding, you should be able to use the same group ids and internal topics, though

Comment: Thanks cricket_007. Nifi doesn't help us, we use Nifi in all our batch flows even with Kafka when we do micro-batch but in this case we have to pass one Kafka message as one target platform message (GCP PubSub) in our case and when we try doing this in Nifi, it slows down with 100's of millions of flow files.

As that an acceptable pattern to just run miltipe kafkaConnect clusters for security preferences. I can't think of any other option.
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a configuration problem. Kafka Connect and Nifi would have to use the same Java libraries and methods at some point

Comment: Yes Kafka Consumer wise they both do same, problem starts when the flow files are passed to target processor in Nifi. Connect works much better. May be in Nifi the provenance operations take more time because of millions of flow files. It doesn't go beyond few thousand files per sec. Agree they same same libraries to source and sink data